# Deleting a record from desktop Chrome IndexedDB vs from android Chrome IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, crud, indexeddb

I am trying to delete a record from IndexedDB using the fallowing code:

```
DB.indexedDB.IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE="readwrite";
window.indexedDB =  window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;

if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window) {
        window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
        window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
        DB.indexedDB.IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE=IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE;
    }

DB.indexedDB.idelete = function( storeName, indexValue, index, keyPathfield ){
    var db = DB.indexedDB.db;
    var transaction = db.transaction([storeName], DB.indexedDB.IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
    var store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    var sindex = store.index(index);

    sindex.get(indexValue).onsuccess = function (event){
        store.delete(event.target.result[keyPathfield]).onsuccess = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+="deleted<br>";
            };
        }
}
```

it calls `onsuccess` but when I add a new record with the same `indexValue` and call `idelete` again and search for the record using the fallowing code:

```
DB.indexedDB.readAll=function(storeName, index){
    var results=document.getElementById("result");
    var db = DB.indexedDB.db;
    var transaction = db.transaction([storeName]);
    var store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    var key = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0);
    var cursor = store.openCursor(key);
    var x=0;

    cursor.onsuccess = function(event){
        var result = event.target.result;
        if(result)
        {
            x++;
            var charx=x.toString();
            results.innerHTML+=charx+result.value[index]+"<br>";
            result.continue();
        }
        else 
        return;
}
```

if I am using Windows Chrome, the record is deleted correctly. But if I am using Android Chrome version M18.1, `readAll` can still find the record but `idelete` can't delete it because it was actually deleted.

Comment: I have a feeling that `event.target.result[keyPathfield]` might be a problem.

Comment: My guess would be that the transaction of the delete isn't commited for some reason, or is still active when you call the readAll function when working on Android. Maybe try to google on the issue maybe it is a know bug in the Android Chrome version.

Comment: @KyawTun the `keyPathfield` has a unique value used as a primary key to store every record and make them unique even if they have similar indexed values. `sindex.get(indexValue)` will bring the first record that have `indexValue` and `event.target.result[keyPathfield]` will uniquely define which record to delete. But why it is working in windows but not in android Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just open key cursor instead of actually retrieving it.

```
sindex.openKeyCursor(indexValue).onsuccess = function (event){
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
      // cursor.delete(); 
      var key = cursor.key;
      var primaryKey = cursor.primaryKey;

      store.delete(primaryKey).onsuccess = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+= key + ' (' + primaryKey + ") deleted<br>";
        };
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+= indexValue + ' not found.<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you check the main page of [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) you will find that `openKeyCursor` is used to find all the records not only the first one and it is a costly operation it might reduce the performance. that is why I use the index approach.

Comment: where you find it? openKeyCursor for exact key (as in this case) should be faster than get.

Comment: getKey() is I think the "faster" thing you'd looking for, though in practice unless your values are huge, there's going to be little difference between get() and getKey()

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that there are multiple transactions in flight at once - I can tell this becuause idelete() doesn't return the transaction it creates, so there's no way to guarantee that readAll() executes after idelete().

instead you're going to need to make idelete() return the transaction, and then handle that:

```
foo = idelete(....).oncomplete = function() { readAll()...}
```

I think the fact that it happens to work in android is just a fluke of the implementation of chrome (which is single-process on android, so events tend to run more serially there)

Comment: I tried to use `transaction.oncomplete=function(event){}` and it is being called only when I call `idelete` for the first time. the next `idelete` call cause `event.target.result[keyPathfield]` to return undefined and doesn't call `transaction.oncomplete=function(event){}`.I am using buttons to call these functions.